# Expression not evaluated in httpd.conf

Tags: php, apache, configuration, webserver

I am trying to come up with a way to switch between projects and production/development through environment variables. However it when I do this:

`Define PROJECT_ROOT osenv('APACHE_PROJECT_ROOT') 
LogMessage ${PROJECT_ROOT}`

The right side of the Define expression is treated as a sting and not evaluated. The result is "osenv('APACHE_PROJECT_ROOT')" instead of the environment variable itself. Any suggestions?

edit: Some further clarification as this post is not getting the views or answers I expected. I want to have a `development`, `staging` and `production` environment.

On my `development` machine, I expect to have multiple apache projects running, each with a `virtualhost` settings file. The correct path to the directory and the `virtualhost` settings could be derived from (OS) environment variables `APACHE_PROJECT_ROOT` and `APACHE_ACTIVE_PROJECT`.

The `staging` and `production` environment would work similar (perhaps simplified, since there is only one project per droplet. It seems to me like common sense to have one http.conf file, where the OS environment variables determine what sites are loaded. I am not really finding any resources on this though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Define` is not documented as taking an expression as an argument, so it should be no surprise that the value ends up as the literal value you specify.

You can use native environment variables directly as values with ${VAR} syntax in most contexts because it is handled why the configuration is read. That resolves any alternate paths to DocumentRoot or log directories, but doesn't give you conditionals.

The most reasonable way to do conditionals at config file parsing time is to pass -D to specify which environment you're in and then  to vary the directives used.

Comment: I will have to process this, but I guess you are right. The apache documentation is very very dense and the only way to find this out is by studying the formal grammar. I came up blank looking for good guides.
Thanks for your suggestion on conditionals. Could you refer to a more elaborate guide on this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `If` keyword, see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if

Something like:

```
<If "osenv('APACHE_ACTIVE_PROJECT') == 'staging'">
   LogMessage "this is staging"
</If>
```

(you also have `Elseif` and `Else` statements)

And the same for the other environments. Of course you would put other directives in each `If` statement. You could even use `SetEnv` to position an Apache environment variable that you could use in other directives (rewrite directives, logging directives, etc.)

Full examples of `If` features is at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html

I would also recommend to put each blocks of configuration, per environment, in specific files and then use `Include` directives.

Comment: Yes, I got that to work, but it does not cover my use case where I want to build a path from OS env variables. As you said, I can use Apache variables for that.

Comment: You could have each specific path hardcoded in each specific `If` block. Otherwise you could pregenerate config files from whatever template or if you insist on variables you should use Apache `mod_perl` module to have a fully dynamic configuration file.  See https://perl.apache.org/start/tips/config.html and https://perl.apache.org/docs/1.0/guide/config.html#Apache_Configuration_in_Perl

Answer (score 1):

I take a somewhat different approach to what I think is essentially the same problem. I only have one virtualhost settings file and define all my settings in there. Then I use different hostnames to access the different projects/environments. For example,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/project1/develop"
    ServerName project1-develop
    ErrorLog "logs/project1-develop-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/project1-develop-access.log" common
    # other configuration settings...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/project1/staging"
    ServerName project1-staging
    ErrorLog "logs/project1-staging-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/project1-staging-access.log" common
    # other configuration settings...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/project1/production"
    ServerName project1-production
    ErrorLog "logs/project1-production-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/project1-production-access.log" common
    # other configuration settings...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/project2/develop"
    ServerName project2-develop
    ErrorLog "logs/project2-develop-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/project2-develop-access.log" common
    # other configuration settings...
</VirtualHost>

# repeat for as many hosts as necessary...
```

Then in `/etc/hosts` I define DNS entries for those hostnames that point to localhost (where I am running apache, you would just use whatever server you are using):

```
127.0.0.1    project1-develop
127.0.0.1    project1-staging
127.0.0.1    project1-production
127.0.0.1    project2-develop
# repeat as necessary
```

And now I can access each of my environments at e.g. `http://project1-develop`, `http://project1-staging` etc.

I realise this isn't an answer to your exact question regarding the use of environment variables but I hope it's helpful anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I realise it's a long time since you asked this question, but I think I have a solution.

The `-D` command-line flag only allows you to define a valueless variable, but the `-C` flag allows you to supply an arbitrary config line that is processed before all files.

So if you can start your http with:

```
apachectl start -C "Define PROJECT_ROOT $APACHE_PROJECT_ROOT"
```

the value will be present, and then the following line will work:

```
LogMessage ${PROJECT_ROOT}
```